# Changing the Host Name of a Web API Project Using Local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Web API. I followed the startup project [found on this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and I was able to create a Web API project that works via IIS Express. Next, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/) and now have my project hosted in IIS (I'm running IIS 7.5 on Windows 7).

I'd like to change the host name to "web-api-test" so I'm not using "localhost". When I change the host name to "web-api-test", I cannot get a response from the endpoint. I'm using POSTMAN (a chrome extension) using the GET verb with the url of "web-api-test/api/values". If I try this in Chrome, a Google search takes over and trys to search for the URL.

How can I change the host name of my Web API project in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont change your hostname but you change your bindings in IIS

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/bindings/binding

Then if you use a public dns-server and you cant change this dnssetting so it resolves to your own computer you uses the hosts file locally on your computer to point the domain to your localhost

http://www.bowerwebsolutions.com/wp/2012/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/

Comment: Using the second link, the page suggested flushing the DNC cache. I did that, re-added the website in IIS and now it seems to be working properly. Thanks for the help!